# Do the sages speak on the possibility that the original tablets Moshe Rabbeinu broke may have had different laws on them than the second set?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, aseres-hadibros, exodus, tablets

We're taught that when Moshe descended from Mt. Sinai, he carried with him a first set of tablets which he shattered on the ground at the sight of the Israelites worshipping a golden calf idol.

I have always wondered about the original tablets and whether their characteristics may have been different from the second set we received.

Something that I always found funny was that the first two laws seem to call out the entire nation for their transgression against him.

1. **I am the L‑rd your G‑d**, Who brought you out of the land of Egypt, out of the house of bondage...
2. **You shall have no other gods before Me.** You shall not make for yourself a graven image...

In my mind, I always had this idea that maybe the first two laws weren't included in the original set because after everything the Israelites had seen and been through, most people would consider the first two laws to be self-evident. They then only became law when we transgressed as G-d had no reason to assume we'd stray until that moment.

That, or the laws may have not been in this original order. The idea being that G-d only moved the first two laws to their beginning position after we transgressed. Once he saw this as our first and biggest mistake, he shuffled the laws and made those two first. If the first misstep of the Israelites had been any  of the other 8 laws, maybe one of those would have been first on the new set?

***Just a thought.***

I was curious if there is any insight into the characteristics of the first set of tablets and whether their laws or qualities might have been different or distinct from the tablets we ultimately received?

Comment: Ex 34:1 "And the Lord said to Moshe, Hew for thyself two tablets of stone like the first: and I will write upon these tablets the words that were on the first tablets, which thou didst break."

Comment: Bava Kama 54B-55A says the word tov was not written in the first but it was in the second. https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.55a.1?lang=bi

Comment: I once heard, can’t recall the source, that has the first Lucia not been broken, we would never of forgotten Torah. It would’ve been like walking and talking, ingrained in our psyche and not forgotten. The second luchos did not have this attribute